# data doesn't show on django template

Tags: python, html, django

[My Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbYqf.png)

[My Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnP7j.png)

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAePz.png)

[My Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRm0X.png)

How can I solve this issue?

The data on the django template don't show but when I change them, it is a number it changed.

Comment: Check rules of stack overflow and delete all of your images
There you should use code not imgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the loop in template like this:

```
{% for item in leave_type %}
   {{ item.id }}
   {{ item.title }}
   {{ item.amount_leave }}
{% endfor %}
```